Как на python + flet в режиме web полностью обновить страницу с помощью браузера
Пример в вакууме:
import os
import flet as ft


async def main(page: ft.Page):
    list_files = os.listdir("some_files")
    print(list_files)

    page.add(ft.Text(list_files))
    page.update()


ft.app(target=main, view=None, port=44051)

Запускаю.
Вижу в браузере(chrome) при запуске:
['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt', 'test5.txt']

Иду в каталог "some_files" и удаляю например любой файл
Жму в браузере кнопку "обновить"(F5):

Список файлов не поменялся

В консоль упала ошибка:
self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]


А если я открою новую вкладку браузера и запущу там приложение то список файлов обновится до актуального состояния.
Как сделать так что бы при обновлении страницы в браузере приложение перезапускалось, другими словами обновлялось по честному?

А если Ctrl+F5? )  А так то хедеры нужно тогда отдавать, что ссылка быстро протухает. Ну там много вариантов.

@CrazyElf Эх если бы всё было так просто, конечно я пробовал, не помогает((

Хм, ну тогда нужно знать, что такое этот flet и как он работает, тут я пас. Так то странно.

@CrazyElf Советую ознакомится, так то приятная штука, если маленькую задачу хочется сделать красиво и быстро. Но информацию вроде этой искать проблемно, в документации не нашёл, gpt плавает в этой теме, на форумах(не только русскоязчных) отвечают редко, видимо пока не достаточно популярная.
